# Actualizar un array, eliminando un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito actualizar un array, habiendo eliminado un elemento.
Tengo una función que carga objetos dentro de un array, y que si encuentra un objeto que es igual en varias características al objeto que se está agregando, a este último le suma "el stock" del item anterior.

```
  //Comparar el libro ingresado con las entradas anteriores
let setStock = ()=> {

    let Libreria = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Libreria"));
    if (Libreria !== null){
        for (item of Libreria) {
            if (item["titulo"] == nuevoLibro.titulo && item["autor"] == nuevoLibro.autor && item["estado"] == nuevoLibro.estado ){

                let x = Libreria.indexOf(item); //Encuentra el index del objeto

                newStock = parseInt(nuevoLibro.stock) + parseInt(item["stock"]); 
                nuevoLibro.stock = newStock;

               console.log(Libreria[x]);  //Llego al punto en que encuentra el objeto dentro del array
                
            } else { console.log("no match");}
        }
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que probé con

> Libreria.splice(x,1)

y con

> var toRemove = Libreria[x];Libreria = Libreria.filter(function(item)
> {return item !== toRemove});

pero siguen apareciendo ambas entradas en el array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, el error no estaba en usar Libreria.splice(x,1). El error estaba en que yo ese array lo guardo y llamo desde localStorage, y nunca usaba el setItem con stringtify para guardarlo. No se si borro o no la pregunta ya que la respuesta no tiene nada que ver.

Amplio la respuesta entonces.
Para eliminar un elemento de un array se puede usar .splice(), la cuestión es que si lo usamos dentro de una función, hay q retornar el valor. En mi caso, yo lo tenía que retornar y luego llamar desde localStorage, y la manera de "cargar" la info ahí es a través de localStorage.setItem("foo", JSON.stringify(foo));

Comment: En tu caso yo desarrollaria un poco más la respuesta explicando mejor la solución a la que has llegado y su código, y al cabo de 12 horas puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

No se si entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Según entiendo yo, quieres tomar un elemento si existe y sumarle al nuevo objeto el stock para, posteriormente, borrar el elemento del array

Puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
const item = libreria.find((item) => item.titulo === nuevoLibro.titulo && item.autor === nuevoLibro.autor && item.estado === nuevoLibro.estado)

nuevoLibro.stock += item?.stock ?? 0 // Con esto haces un null-safe

libreria = libreria.filter((item) => item.titulo !== nuevoLibro.titulo && item.autor !== nuevoLibro.autor && item.estado !== nuevoLibro.estado)
```

Comment: Exactamente. Para hacerlo más claro con un ejemplo: arrLibros [{nombre: X, autor: Y, stock: 1}, ...], si le agrego un elemento con nombre X y autor X, que sume el stock y deje solamente la última entrada (o sea que elimina la anterior que tiene el stock anterior.
Probé con tu solución pero sigo con el mismo problema, que cuando quiero usar nuevamente el array, tiene ambos elementos, el nuevo con el stock correcto, y el anterior como estaba.